# ¿Cómo muestro en un TextBox más de una variable?

Tags: c#, windows-forms

Un ejemplo `textbox.tex=array[0];`, pero también me gustaría en el mismo TextBox imprimir otra variable incluido un salto de linea. Por ejemplo:

> ```
> hola
> 12
> adiós
> ```

Todo eso en un TextBox

Comment: Parece que tienes un error en tu código, ¿debería ser textbox.Text=array[0]; en vez de textbox.tex=array[0]; ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes crear saltos de línea con `\r\n` o `Environment.NewLine`

Tu código quedaría así:

Con `\r\n`:

```
textbox.Text = array[0] + "\r\n" + variable;
```

Con `Environment.NewLine`:

```
textbox.Text = array[0] + Environment.NewLine + variable;
```

En este [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/system.environment.newline.aspx) hay más información sobre `Environment.NewLine`

Answer (score 4):

Siendo `txtBox1` tu control TextBox, tienes que habilitar la propiedad `Multiline`.

```
txtBox1.Multiline = true;
```

Luego, para asignarle valores podrías usar `string.format`. Por ejemplo:

```
txtBox1.Text = string.Format("{0}\r\n{1}\r\n{2}", "Hola", 12, "adiós");
```

O usando interpolación de cadenas:

```
txtBox1.Text = $"{"Hola"}\r\n{12}\r\n{"adiós"}";
```

Mostrará:

[image: Ejemplo salto línea]

---

**Referencia:**

- [Interpolación de cadenas en C#](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/csharp/tutorials/string-interpolation)
- [Método String.Format](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.string.format(v=vs.110).aspx)